# Ng bootstrap dropdown not in front

Tags: html, angular, sass, ng-bootstrap

I am using [Ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) in an Angular 5 project. I am trying to create a dropdown in my navigation header, and i've managed to make it work, however it is in the background of the things in my container - and i'd of course like it to be in front.

This is how it looks now:

[image]

I haven't managed to make ng-bootstrap work in a Plunker, so i'll share the relevant code here.
This is my header.component.html file:

```
<div class="my-header">
<header class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">

<a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">HELLO</a>

<button aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" (click)="toggleCollapse()">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" [@collapse]="collapse" id="navbarContent">

  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/main/memberships']">Memberships</a>
    </li>

    <div ngbDropdown placement="bottom-right" class="d-inline-block">
      <li class="nav-item nav-link dropdown my-header-but" id="DropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Profile</li>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu class="my-dropdown" aria-labelledby="DropdownBasic1">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/main/profile']">Your profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/main/profile']">Paid subscriptions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/main/profile']">Payment history</a>
        </li>
        <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="logOut()">Log out</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The components in the  blocking typically looks like random.component.html:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
       All kinds of content
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This is my custom scss:

```
.my-header {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  background-color: $secondary-bg;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-color: $accent-color;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 5px -10px $black;
}

.my-header-but {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  background-color: $gray-900;
  box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -7px $black, -12px 0 15px -7px $black, 0 12px 
  15px -7px $black;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

The computed style on the dropdown is as shown here[image]:

The style on the  element going in front of the dropdown is simply:

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
```

I have tried adjusting the z-index on different elements without any luck. I can see in the browser that the style changes do get applied to the elements.
So how would you proceed to try to get it in front?
Please let me know i you need more information on anything else.

**UPDATE:**

I've found that changing the z-index of the  with the 'col' class help's and put's the underlying div beneath the dropdown. I'd of course like to bring the header and dropdowns in front of everything - not have the bring everything behind that. But it seems like it's something about the structure of my header.

**UPDATE 2:**

Adding z-index: 1010 to:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" [@collapse]="collapse" 
id="navbarContent">
```

fixed it. I don't know why it isn't that z-index already, thought bootstrap would take care of that. But i won't dig further into that for now.

Thanks for the answers everyone.

Comment: I know you said that you already tired using z-index but have you tried making the box that's over the profile options a negative z-index

Comment: Hadn't tried that actually! But did now and it didn't make much of a difference unfortunately.

Comment: after adding your css properties make sure on your browser developer view that your css property is actually being applied and that your cache is cleared because sometime your browser can hold onto old cache,  you can do this by click and hold on Ctrl - F5 (on windows)

Comment: Have you tried: `:host { z-index: 1000000; }` in the header component CSS?

Comment: I have tried adding it, but i doesn't seem to compute. Where exactly do i need to add it? I'm not quite sure about what the ':host' tag means.

Comment: If your custom SCSS is compiled outside of the component, you can try: `app-header { z-index: 1000000; }`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but just came across the same issue.

I solved it by placing relative and absolute containers around the dropdown, and applying z-index inside the dropdown:

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item" ngbDropdown>
            <a class="nav-link" id="tselect" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" ngbDropdownToggle>
                {{user.company}}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="tselect">
                <button ngbDropdownItem>... text ...</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the component SCSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    ul.nav {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1010;
    }
}
```

In my case I couldn't use z-index on the .navbar-collapse as it's width was modified when this dropdown content grew large.

Answer (score -2):

First, you should get the dropdown. I'll assume it is

```
<div ngbDropdownMenu class="my-dropdown" aria-labelledby="DropdownBasic1">
```

Since it has a directive attribute and you tried to style it.

On this element, you must check if its `position` is everything except `static` or `initial`.

Once you have checked that, you can modify the z-index of this element

```
.my-dropdown { z-index: 9999 !important; }
```

But what you need to see, is if your component is encapsulated or not. You can see that into the decorat `@Component`. If you don't see `ViewEncapsulation.none`, then your component is encapsulated.

This means that it will add custom attributes to your component tags, and therefore remove some styles you tried to apply (I didn't figure out which ones yet).

In this case, you need to place your class into your root style, which is usually `style.css` (or scss or less).

After that, it should work like a charm !

Comment: The position is absolute.
I have tried to add { z-index: 9999 !important; } to the dropdown class and i can see in the inspect that it gets the attribute. However it is still behind the elements in the body.

Comment: @Lars Did you read my answer ? I spent like 15 minutes writing it down to break it to you ...

Comment: I did. And thank you for answering! But i don't think it's that unfortunately. 
I have only one scss file where all of my components get their styles from, so i don't think encapsulation is the issue.

Comment: Then maybe you should have started with that ... Could you inspect your element and give us his computed style ? Could you also give the computed style of the component that is above it and hides it ?

Comment: I have added that to the screenshot now. Thanks.

Comment: ... I have no access to imgur because of the corporate proxy :'D

Comment: I see :-D Here's a link with the picture https://www.justbeamit.com/smx2y

Comment: Thank you ! So which one is over your dropdown ?

Comment: @Lars (and the position doesn't seem to be set as `relative` or `absolute`, is that normal ?)

Comment: The div over the dropdown is described in the question, but it only has display: block and box-sizing: border-box.
The one in the picture is the dropdown itself.
Isn't the position set to absolute in .dropdown-menu class?

Comment: My bad, didn't see the media at the top. since the dropdown is in absolute position, could you check the first ancestor of his that is in non-static position ? absolute elements position themselves from the first non-static element they find in their ancestors. Maybe your dropdown is simply out of the page !

Comment: try to give to your nav-bar a z-index greater than the z-index of your overlapped layer